# spring tool suite git perspective broken

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have problem with the Git perspective of STS, it seems that the right click menu is all empty, any idea why?

[broken Git perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsMb0.png)

Comment: that looks strange indeed. It works for all the other perspectives? And is there anything in the Error Log view showing up that might be related to this issue?

Comment: Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\me'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

Comment: does not sound like something that could cause the issue mentioned above. Does this happen with a vanilla STS installation, too? You could also start STS with a "-clean" option, maybe that helps, reset the perspective might be another option. Other than that, I would recommend to try a fresh STS install and if that works, start from there. If this happens again, record the steps that led to this situation and report a bug via https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that it only happens with STS 4.6 64 bits, and does not happen with STS 4.5.2 64 bits